# Statistics P-Value

Tags: statistics

A researcher wanted to determine if carpeted rooms contain more bacteria than uncarpeted rooms. The table shows the results for the number of bacteria per cubic foot for both types of rooms.
Carpeted:
15.9; 8.7; 14.1; 14.3; 6; 10.3; 13.9; 13.7

Uncarpeted:
6.9; 5.7; 5.1; 6.4; 8; 8.9; 9; 13.4

Determine whether carpeted rooms have more bacteria than uncarpeted rooms at the α= 0.01 level of significance. Assume the data are approximately normal and that there are no outliers.

H0: µ1=µ2
H1: µ1>µ2
These are the values:

Population 1:
N=8
x¯ : 10.3
σ: 8.475

Population 2:
N=8
x¯ : 3.0840604
σ: 3.1148263

I've already gotten to the point where I've solved the T value, which is 2.260398849. But I cannot figure out how to get the P-Value. I've looked at Chi-tables at the Degrees of Freedom, which is 7. But I still cannot understand where/how to get the solution. I'm using mymathlab, so I know what the answer is (multiple attempts w/ wrong answer). It's .014, but like I said, I have no idea where that number came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you've calculated your sample means correctly.  For instance, the uncarpeted sample has values all greater than $5$, yet the sample mean you reported is only $3.08$, which doesn't make any sense.  Either your samples are reported incorrectly, or your calculations of the sample means and standard deviations are incorrect.

Next, from the data, we can see that the sample variances are not similar.  Therefore, the assumption that the population variances of these two groups are equal is unlikely to be true, and we probably shouldn't use a pooled variance.  Therefore, the test statistic should take on the form $$T = \frac{\bar x_1 - \bar x_2}{\sqrt{s_1^2/n_1 + s_2^2/n_2}},$$ where $s_1^2, s_2^2$ are the sample variances, $n_1, n_2$ are the sample sizes, and $\bar x_1, \bar x_2$ are the sample means.  This test statistic **approximately** follows a Student's $t$-distribution with $$\nu = \frac{(s_1^2/n_1 + s_2^2/n_2)^2}{\frac{(s_1^2/n_1)^2}{n_1-1} + \frac{(s_2^2/n_2)^2}{n_2-1}}$$ degrees of freedom (this is known as Satterthwaite's approximation, and the test is known as Welch's $t$-test).  In your case, this would give a test statistic of $T \approx 2.75386$, with $\nu \approx 13$ degrees of freedom.  The $p$-value is $$2 (1 - \Pr[T \le 2.75386]) \approx 0.0164;$$ that is to say, it is the probability that a Student's $t$-distributed random variable with $13$ degrees of freedom has absolute value greater than $2.75386$ (2-tailed test).  In Wolfram|Alpha or *Mathematica*, you can get this value by typing

```
 2 (1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[13], 2.75386])
```

Or if you do not have the ability to calculate the cumulative distribution function of the $t$-distribution, you would conduct the hypothesis test at the $\alpha = 0.01$ significance level by looking up the test statistic in a $t$-table.  With $13$ degrees of freedom, the critical value is the upper $99.5^{\rm th}$ percentile $t_{13, 0.005} = 2.97684$.  Since the test statistic is smaller in absolute value, the conclusion is that we fail to reject the null hypothesis:  the sample provides *insufficient evidence* to support the claim that the population means are different with at least $99\%$ confidence.

While it may seem counterintuitive--the data seems to suggest there is a difference in means--the reason why we fail to reject is because (a) the sample sizes are rather small, at $n_1 = n_2 = 8$ each; and (b) the significance level is quite strict at only $1\%$, meaning that we are only willing to commit a Type I error (incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis when the null is true) at most $1\%$ of the time.  This is a high standard to meet for such a small sample.

Note that you get the same test statistic if you assume equal group variances, because the sample sizes are equal; but the degrees of freedom is different.

Comment: You're correct I did inadvertently copy the wrong samples off of a different question. But thank you for your help.